# AWS Kinesis, Lambda and VPC endpoint

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-kinesis, amazon-vpc

I have a firehose Lambda function that need to aggregate some data push them to an RDS mysql server. The records that were aggregate successfully are send to a S3 bucket and the failed ones should be sent to Kinesis.

First I have tested it with no VPC and the failed requests were pushed back to Kinesis. Than  I have added a VPC and the requests failed to be pushed back.

I have learned that a VPC endpoint can be created so I have created one added the VPC subnets and the security group I was using inside the lambda function for connection to RDS.

I have tried to run the lambda again but failed the connection to lambda timed out as before. I don't see a way to add the vpc endpoint to the lambda function as well.

As I understand from the documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/streams/latest/dev/vpc.html I should not change the code inside the lambda and I should work out of the box.

My current setup:
Lambda function is under a VPC having 2 subnets A and B and one security group to SG. Lambda function has full rights to Kinesis and S3, so is not a rights issue.
The code from the Function has a default put records function which send the records to the Kinesis stream, named KS, nothing special just default implementation of put records.
VPC endpoint was created to have access to the kinesis stream I wanna write, named KS, have access to subnets A and B as well as the SG security group.

What am I doing wrong? What i missed in this hole picture?
What should I do with the VPC endpoint after I created it?

Comment: Did you enable private DNS for the interface endpoint you created?   It is not entirely clear how many SGs you have, but the answer appears to be just 1... but if the Kinesis endpoint and the Lambda function use the same security group, then that security group must have a rule that allows HTTPS access *from itself* -- listing sg-xxxx instead of an IP address as the source.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I am sure I did not enabled the DNS interface. Also I will add the https access. And yes is only one security group.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot after I added the DNS where should I use it and how?

Comment: You don't need to do anything to use it.  This is the feature that makes "no code changes" possible -- it changes the DNS record for Kinesis from an Internet destination to an internal destination (the endpoint).

Comment: Check this, too: [*To use private DNS, you must set the following VPC attributes to true: `enableDnsHostnames` and `enableDnsSupport`.*](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpce-interface.html#vpce-private-dns) These are VPC-level options.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot thank you it worked like a charm. Also thanks for the  link ;)

Comment: Which changes were needed?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Setting the of DNS and the alow of https

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot If the one who connects the Kinesis has regular access to HTTPS, How do you know that the actual kinesis endpoint is being used instead of the common internet endpoint? Is there a way we can validate this?